# Build boost with VS2012 RC

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2012

I've just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 RC for Windows 8 64 bit. I've tried to compile boost libraries (version 1.51), but when I make, inside the Visual Studio prompt command, I've an error. I post the bootstrap.log at the end of the post. I'd like to know what's the correct procedure to build boost on VS2012RC on Windows 8 Release Candidate.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

```
###
### Using 'vc11' toolset.
###

C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\boost_1_51_0\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\engine>if
exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap

C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\boost_1_51_0\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\engine>md
bootstrap

C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\boost_1_51_0\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\engine>cl
/nologo /RTC1 /Zi /MTd /Fobootstrap/ /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG
-wd4996 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0
command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execnt.c filent.c function.c
glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c
make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c regexp.c
rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c
strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c pwd.c class.c w32_getreg.c
native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c
modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c
command.c
compile.c
constants.c
debug.c
execnt.c
filent.c
function.c
glob.c
hash.c
hdrmacro.c
headers.c
jam.c
jambase.c
jamgram.c
lists.c
make.c
make1.c
object.c
option.c
output.c
Generazione del codice in corso...
Compilazione in corso...
parse.c
pathunix.c
regexp.c
rules.c
scan.c
search.c
subst.c
timestamp.c
variable.c
modules.c
strings.c
filesys.c
builtins.c
md5.c
pwd.c
class.c
w32_getreg.c
native.c
set.c
path.c
Generazione del codice in corso...
Compilazione in corso...
regex.c
property-set.c
sequence.c
order.c
Generazione del codice in corso...

C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\boost_1_51_0\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\engine>.\bootstrap    \jam0
-f build.jam --toolset=vc11 "--toolset-root=C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\ " clean
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
...updated 1 target...

C:\Users\XXX\Downloads\boost_1_51_0\boost_1_51_0\tools\build\v2\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0
-f build.jam --toolset=vc11 "--toolset-root=C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\ "
don't know how to make command.c
don't know how to make compile.c
don't know how to make constants.c
don't know how to make debug.c
don't know how to make function.c
don't know how to make glob.c
don't know how to make hash.c
don't know how to make hcache.c
don't know how to make headers.c
don't know how to make hdrmacro.c
don't know how to make jam.c
don't know how to make jambase.c
don't know how to make jamgram.c
don't know how to make lists.c
don't know how to make make.c
don't know how to make make1.c
don't know how to make mem.c
don't know how to make object.c
don't know how to make option.c
don't know how to make output.c
don't know how to make parse.c
don't know how to make regexp.c
don't know how to make rules.c
don't know how to make scan.c
don't know how to make search.c
don't know how to make subst.c
don't know how to make w32_getreg.c
don't know how to make timestamp.c
don't know how to make variable.c
don't know how to make modules.c
don't know how to make strings.c
don't know how to make filesys.c
don't know how to make builtins.c
don't know how to make pwd.c
don't know how to make class.c
don't know how to make native.c
don't know how to make md5.c
don't know how to make modules/set.c
don't know how to make modules/path.c
don't know how to make modules/regex.c
don't know how to make modules/property-set.c
don't know how to make modules/sequence.c
don't know how to make modules/order.c
don't know how to make execnt.c
don't know how to make filent.c
don't know how to make pathunix.c
...found 50 targets...
...updating 1 target...
...can't find 46 targets...
...can't make 2 targets...
[MKDIR] bin.ntx86_64
...skipped b2.exe for lack of command.c...
...skipped bjam.exe for lack of b2.exe...
...skipped 2 targets...
...updated 1 target...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

workaround:

1. change directory to boost_1_51_0-x64\tools\build\v2
2. execute bootstrap.bat (not from the the native x64 comand prompt - just double click it)
3. copy b2.exe back to boost_1_51_0-x64 dir
4. change directory to boost_1_51_0-x64
5. execute b2

I programmed a tool called BlueGo which automatically downloads boost 1.51.0 and builds it with VS2012 x64:
http://vertexwahn.de/

Comment: It compiled successfully. Thanks

Comment: The tool now supports also Boost 1.52.0 and Boost 1.53.0

Comment: @Vertexwahn i've tryied your app, it said boos has installed succesfully, but when i include let's say #include <boost/asio.hpp> gives error, what should i do next?

Comment: @ddacot BlueGo does not set the include and lib directories for Visual Studio - you have to set them manually. This can be done manually via Properties->Project->C/C++->Additional Include files or via a build system like CMake (see here: https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/cmakedemos/src/dec91489b1f0dcb0770390cdee6363996849d41b/boostFilesystemTest/CMakeLists.txt?at=default) This is handled this way because it should be possible to use different boost versions for different projects. Also not every developer has located boost in the same directory - you can create a feature request if you like

Comment: i've done this but still get 3 errors http://s7.directupload.net/images/130523/v877ojgf.jpg

Comment: @ddacot Properties->Project->Linker (General)->Additional Library Directories

Answer (score 7):

[Version 1.52](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html)  was just released and now includes support for Visual Studio 2012 (VC11) If you require an earlier version of Boost you can always change the toolset used by the project to VC10.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer, but you can download prebuilt Boost binaries built with VC11 RC [here](http://boost.teeks99.com/). Based on this page, there seem to be some problems building Boost on VC11 (see [this thread](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2012/08/195729.php))

Answer (score 1):

For windows8 check out this patch https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/7243/boost_1_51_0_win8_x64_compat.patch