# Will boost compile with VS2012?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

I am currently using VS2010 (compiler v10). Will I be able to use Boost with VS2012 (compiler v11)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build boost with VS2012 RC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149524/build-boost-with-vs2012-rc)

Comment: Note that VS2012 may behave quite differently from RC version

Comment: Note that there was an Update for VS2012 (Nov 2012) and you can use the 2010 Compiler with the VS2012 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_51_0.html . At the bottom, there is compiler information.

There is currently no official support for VC higher than 10. But you can try yourself, and possibly you should also read the release notes of your compiler. It should only fail to compile if boost uses non-standard extensions and/or if the compiler has relevant bugs.

<sub>(google hint: "boost compiler support", or just go to boost, click on the release notes of the version you desire)</sub>

Comment: Possibly. I gave the official answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Reason is quite simple. Like Herb Sutter said. 2 libraries that **must** compile before they ship compiler are Loki and Boost. :D  Ofc there might be a chance for eg. that they tested with 1.47 and that something broke in 1.51 but I wouldn't bet on it. :D

Answer (score 2):

[Version 1.52](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html)  was just released and now includes support for Visual Studio 2012 (VC11) under the "additional test compilers" section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (padding because an answer must be at least 30 characters)

Comment: Do you know of any version limitations? I have Boost 1.49 installed and I want to use C++11 features..

Comment: @Queequeg Why would there be any version limitations? Old versions of `boost` should work just fine. Only that it won't make use of the new C++11 feature set.

Comment: @Queequeg are you asking me if Microsoft's C++ compiler is suddenly no longer able to compile C++ code? The answer is "no, Microsoft's C++ compiler is still a C++ compiler, which means that it is able to compile C++ code". In other news, even the latest models of airplanes are still able to fly, and the 2012 models of cars can still drive on roads

Comment: No need to be rude. I was just asking if, perhaps, there are some (known) compatibility issues (e.g. due to new syntax). For instance, boost uses macros a lot and it's obvious, that macros aren't too intelligent and I would like to know it they will handle code that is filled with lambdas etc.

Comment: FYI: [Breaking Changes in Visual C++ 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx).  Thankfully, only a small percentage of cars and planes suffer from breaking changes ;)